# HTML5 Audio: Which source was used?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

Is there a way to determine which `source` was used when specifying multiple sources to an HTML5 `audio` element?

E.g. I have this HTML code:

```
<audio preload="auto">
    <source type="audio/ogg;codecs=vorbis" src="http://example.org/sample.ogg"/>
    <source type="audio/mpeg;codecs=mp3" src="http://example.org/sample.mp3"/>
</audio>
```

Now I want to know if the ogg or the mp3 file was used. I tried to register `onload` and `onloadeddata` event handlers on the `source` elements but they where never called. Also `src` of the `audio` element is unchanged after load and the `source` elements don't have a `readyState` property.

Can this be found out in any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Register a function for `onloadeddata` of the `audio` element, in that look at the [`currentSrc`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#dom-media-currentsrc).